# Refactoring excessive conditional logic

Tags: c#

I am interested in any "tools" to really cut down on if/else statements. For example, in the case of having a person with a heading (i.e. North, South, etc), and an instruction (move forward, back, left, etc) which are 8 different possible branches, how could I refactor that into something less repetitive?

E.g. if (person.Heading = "N" && person.Instruction = "Move Forward)

And so on for every other possible permutation.

I am using .NET 4.0. LINQ is acceptable (although I'd like to know both modern and "old-skool" approaches).

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say with limited information, although a state machine or the full state pattern might prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try implementing the state pattern as @anthonypegram suggested. Take a look at this link for more info http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the usual sources for State Pattern, GOF, Refactoring to Patterns, etc., I have found this paper very useful: **Transform Conditionals: a Reengineering Pattern Language** -
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.7194

The paper presents four (4) patterns for Transforming Conditionals more flexible structures:

- Self Conditional to SubClassing
- Transform Client Conditional to Polymorphism
- Apply State
- Apply NullObject

It organizes approaches to problem and contains references to other sources.
Useful to me even thought 20+ years old.

Comment: Could you quote some parts of the paper that might offer ways to solve OPs question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a function just for this scenario then using a Switch statement (which is one alternative). The function would be just dedicated to this purpose of finding what to do when all the different scenario's arise. Let me know if this helped. You are familiar with Linq so no need to mention. Have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Obviously state patterns is mentioned in above comment.

Comment: I can, but really want to find a way to do the same thing without if/else or switch. Table-driven-methods were one way...